# Ruby Regexp character class with new line, why not match?

Tags: ruby

I want to use this regex to match any block comment (c-style) in a string.
But why the below does not?

```
rblockcmt = Regexp.new "/\\*[.\s]*?\\*/"  # match block comment
p rblockcmt=~"/* 22/Nov - add fee update */"

==> nil
```

Comment: There's some prior art out there... start here: http://blog.ostermiller.org/find-comment

Comment: After the first line you may wish to show the return value: `#=> /\/\*[. ]*?\*\//`

Answer (score 3):

And in addition to what Sir Swoveland posted, a `.` matches any character *except a newline*:

> The following metacharacters also behave like character classes:
>
> `/./` - Any character except a newline.
>
> https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html

If you need `.` to match a newline, you can specify the `m` flag, e.g.  `/.*?/m`

> Options
>
> The end delimiter for a regexp can be followed by one or more
>   single-letter options which control how the pattern can match.
>
> `/pat/i` - Ignore case
>   `/pat/m` - Treat a newline as a character matched by `.`
>   ...
>
> https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html

Because having exceptions/quirks like newline not matching a `.` can be painful, some people specify the `m` option for every regex they write.

Comment: Thank you, the /m option work for me :). Finally I use /\/\*.*?\*\//m

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you intend `[.\s]*?` to match any character or a whitespace, zero or more times, lazily. Firstly, whitespaces are characters, so you don't need `\s`. That simplifies your expression to `[.]*?`. Secondly, if your intent is to match any character there is no need for a character class, just write `.`. Thirdly, *and most importantly*, a period within a character class is simply the character `"."`.

You want `.*?` (or `[^*]*`).

Comment: my intend is to use \s to matches spaces, tab, new line. the dot . to match other character but it does not :)